# Generate Resx file dynamically at application startup

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization, transifex

The main issue we trying to solve is whenever there is a change in the words of the translation. We should only change in the [Transifex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transifex) and the application should get reflected, and no deployment is required.

I was trying to generate the *.resx* file from the Transifex API on the application startup. As whenever there is a change in the Transifex, when we deploy the application, it should automatically download the translations and generate the *.resx* file that application will use for localization.

But the *.resx* files are tightly coupled with the MVC view pages, so at run time I wasn't able to overwrite the *.resx* files (embedded resource).

Is there a way I can achieve this?